# mongodb array string element query

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am querying array of strings in mongdb and it does not work with $gt/$lt operators, see below. "cpu" array 3rd element is string "12"

```
nms:PRIMARY> db.checkpoints.find({ "cpu.3": "12" }).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5665ed5d601be0ed56d4ca0a"), "day" : "1", "hostname" : "WAL-VSX-02", "time" : "15:33:54", "con" : [ "75", "44", "10", "25997", "8895", "13788", "338", "20", "226" ], "cpu" : [ "0", "0", "0", "12", "0", "2", "0", "0", "0" ], "__v" : 0 }
nms:PRIMARY> db.checkpoints.find({ "cpu.3": {$gte: 10}})
nms:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to query by a particular array index? Thats going to be very fragile code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason you are not getting any output is because "cpu" is an array of string. You will need to use the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator which does a JavaScript evaluation and cannot take advantage of indexes as mentioned in the [documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#considerations)

```js
db.checkpoints.find({ "$where": function() {
    return parseFloat(this.cpu[3]) >= 10;
}})
```

I'll suggest you change your document structure and convert "cpu" elements to float.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the values of the `cpu` array as strings, but you are comparing against an integer. If you change the array to int values your query will work.